# Contar a ocorrência de combinações de strings sem que a ordem importe

Tags: r, dplyr

Suponha que eu tenha um conjunto de dados com as colunas `pais_1` e `pais_2`. Eu desejo contar quantas vezes cada combinação de países ocorre neste conjunto de dados. Veja o exemplo abaixo para mais detalhes.

```r
dados <- structure(list(pais_1 = c("Argentina", "Chile", "Argentina", 
                                   "Brasil", "Argentina", "Chile",
                                   "Chile", "Brasil", "Brasil", 
                                   "Chile"), 
                        pais_2 = c("Chile", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
                                   "Argentina", "Brasil", "Brasil", 
                                   "Brasil", "Brasil", "Chile", 
                                   "Argentina")), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

dados
#>       pais_1    pais_2
#> 1  Argentina     Chile
#> 2      Chile Argentina
#> 3  Argentina Argentina
#> 4     Brasil Argentina
#> 5  Argentina    Brasil
#> 6      Chile    Brasil
#> 7      Chile    Brasil
#> 8     Brasil    Brasil
#> 9     Brasil     Chile
#> 10     Chile Argentina

dados |> 
  count(pais_1, pais_2) |> 
  arrange(desc(n))
#>      pais_1    pais_2 n
#> 1     Chile Argentina 2
#> 2     Chile    Brasil 2
#> 3 Argentina Argentina 1
#> 4 Argentina    Brasil 1
#> 5 Argentina     Chile 1
#> 6    Brasil Argentina 1
#> 7    Brasil    Brasil 1
#> 8    Brasil     Chile 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As ocorrências `Chile-Argentina` e `Chile-Brasil` são as mais comuns, ocorrendo 2 vezes cada uma. Entretanto, a ordem não importa para mim, ou seja, para o fim que necessito, `Chile-Argentina` e `Argentina-Chile` tem o mesmo propósito. Desta forma, as linhas 5 (`Argentina-Chile`) e 8 (`Brasil-Chile`) deveriam estar contando no resultado final. Ou seja, eu espero obter uma tabela tipo esta para este exemplo:

```r
#>      pais_1    pais_2 n
#> 1     Chile Argentina 3
#> 2     Chile    Brasil 3
#> 3 Argentina    Brasil 2
#> 4 Argentina Argentina 1
#> 5    Brasil    Brasil 1
```

A ordem dos nomes dos países não importa neste caso. As colunas sequer precisam se chamar `pais_1` e `pais_2` no resultado final.

Como obter isto? Alguma ideia de pré-processamento nos dados iniciais ou na primeira tabela que obtive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baseado em seu exemplo e premissa de que ordem não importa, é possível unir as colunas, agregar, e finalmente separar as colunas novamente.

Repare que ao unir as colunas é obrigatório que seja em ordem alfabética para que se possa contar corretamente.

```
data.frame(table(par_paises = sapply(split(as.matrix(dados), row(dados)), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse="|")))) %>% 
    separate( par_paises, into=c("A", "B"), sep= "\\|") %>% 
    arrange(desc(Freq))

          A         B Freq
1 Argentina     Chile    3
2    Brasil     Chile    3
3 Argentina    Brasil    2
4 Argentina Argentina    1
5    Brasil    Brasil    1
```

Answer (score 2):

## R base

Uma solução R base é a seguinte:

1. ordenar os países em cada linha de modo a que a ordem original não tenha importância;
2. usar `aggregate` para ficar só com a primeira linha correspondente aos grupos definidos pelo vetor obtido acima;
3. contar quantos elementos tem cada grupo com `table`;
4. finalmente, juntar as duas tabelas dos pontos anteriores com `merge`.

```r
s <- apply(dados, 1, \(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = "."))
merge(
  aggregate(as.matrix(dados) ~ s, FUN = \(x) x[1]),
  table(s) |> as.data.frame(responseName = "n")
)[-1]
#>      pais_1    pais_2 n
#> 1 Argentina Argentina 1
#> 2    Brasil Argentina 2
#> 3 Argentina     Chile 3
#> 4    Brasil    Brasil 1
#> 5     Chile    Brasil 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## `tidyverse`

A solução `tidyverse` seguinte também começa por ordenar e concatenar os países linha a linha. Depois conta estes resultados e separa a coluna ordenada em colunas com os dois países.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

dados %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(ord = paste(sort(c(pais_1, pais_2)), collapse = ".")) %>%
  count(ord) %>%
  tidyr::separate(ord, c("pais_1", "pais_2"))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   pais_1    pais_2        n
#>   <chr>     <chr>     <int>
#> 1 Argentina Argentina     1
#> 2 Argentina Brasil        2
#> 3 Argentina Chile         3
#> 4 Brasil    Brasil        1
#> 5 Brasil    Chile         3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção usando *igraph*:

```
library(igraph)

grafo <- graph_from_data_frame(dados, directed = FALSE)

as.data.frame(table(as_ids(E(grafo))))
#>                  Var1 Freq
#> 1 Argentina|Argentina    1
#> 2    Argentina|Brasil    2
#> 3     Argentina|Chile    3
#> 4       Brasil|Brasil    1
#> 5        Chile|Brasil    3
```